# What is the proper way to enable CORS on back end using spring security. Also using Apache cxf in the project for REST framework

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, cors, cxf

I have following code snippet(along with a few other configurations). What more should be done? The error from chrome is: 
"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

SC:
[Screenshot for ResponseHeaders from the page to which rxjs(Using angular) call is made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUKNl.png)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
protected  class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }
@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    protected CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge((long) 3600);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        //configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        //configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        //configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList( "x-requested-with","X-requested-with", "authorization", "cache-control", "Content-Type,adminUserId"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {         
        http
        .anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/rest/services/messagePosting/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/services/messagePosting/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());     
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
            throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("my-rest-services");
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur response code is 200

I am adding some more configs that we a re using.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: this solution is for Spring-boot only.**
Can't recall the exact scenario, but I guess it was with OAuth2 configuration where I faced the similar issue when I was configuring CORS in a configuration class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, but that didn't help.
The solution I found was to configure the CORS in a separate java class and import that class into your spring security configuration class. Like below:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {   

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> customCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<Filter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Your security configfuration class(notice the import annotation):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import({CorsConfig.class})
protected  class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Where is FilterRegistrationBean class? spring BOOT? We are not using spring boot.

Comment: Yes, its a Spring boot class. Adding this to answer.

Comment: Any reason to downvote? It's a tried solution for Spring-boot app and I clearly mentioned the "spring-boot" here. I haven't deleted the answer, it could be useful for the Spring-boot users.